# Bluetooth keyboard won't connect until PIN verification

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I want to connect my bluetooth keyboard (macintosh) at Startup.

> But what should i say, i have to enter a PIN, without a keyboard is
>   connected...

Is there a way to connect my keyboard without to buy a USB-Keyboard?

My mouse won't connect, too - i have to enter a PIN there as well!

EDIT: I have a Thinkpad x60s, too. Is there any chance to pair my thinkpad (ubuntu) with my machine (ubuntu) via bluetooth?

Comment: I entered about thousands of terminal commands to get Ubuntu work on my MacMini, and now i cannot do anything because of those stupid things... -.- Why Ubuntu don't let me enter my PIN with the keyboard, OS X does it. It would be so great to have a work-around...

Comment: How you've managed to receive the "Enter pin" dialog?

Comment: It pops up automatically. When i turn my apple keyboard on, the dialog appears. I found no other way to connect the bluetooth-keyboard and mouse then buying a USB-Mouse. Perhabs something important for the Ubuntu-Developers.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very easy task and I had no problems with a bluethooth keyboard (Thinkpad).

**A)** You can use the "add new device" wizard of Ubuntus **standard bluetoth wizard** (indicator symbol or system settings). It gives you a number. This number you simply enter on your keyboard, an press enter. Then the dialogue vanished and devices are paired.

OR

**B)** Use **Blueman** (`sudo apt-get install blueman`) and the "pair" command to easily add new devices.

1. search for new devices with blueman
2. right an press "pair"
3. enter "0000" on your **UBUNTU PC** (you can use any custom number
   you like)
4. hit ENTER or press "OK" on the pc-dialogu
5. immediately **AFTER THAT**, type "0000" on your **BLUETOOTH
   KEYBOARD**
6. hit ENTER on the keyboard

That's it. Devices paired.

Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS with Blueman and a Thinkpad Bluethooth keyboard (which should be same as a mac keyboard, due to bluetooth standard for input devices) on a Thinkpad W510, a Thinkpad X201 and a hinkpad X61s.